# modify django templates in production

Tags: django, nginx, ubuntu-16.04, gunicorn

Okay this might be a bad question but as someone who is new to django production I am a little lost

I have deployed my django project on Ubuntu 16.04 with a nginx, gunicorn and postgres stack.  I am trying to make some simple template changes in the project (adding content in the .html templates) but the changes aren't showing up when I restart gunicorn and nginx.

All I can find online is reference to the collectstatic command which only seems to collect css, js and img...

How would I go about serving the updated template files?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: There is nothing to do. But why are you making changes in production?

Comment: I'm sorry what do you mean there is nothing to do?  I am trying to just alter some html content?  There must be a way to do this

Comment: Yes, you just change it, nothing else. But don't do it in production, although that isn't related to your problem.

Comment: If changes are not showing, are you sure you are modifying the correct files? Django looks for templates in several locations, and might use another template file with the same name, if it is in a location with higher priority.

Comment: Do you have template cacheing enabled? Your template config in your settings file(s) should be easy to check. If there's cacheing enabled, try flushing your cache, too

Comment: In addition to what Roseman said, you only have to reload gunicorn if you change .py files.

Comment: What is the command for flushing the template cache?